# Get windows 8 start background image

Tags: windows, background, windows-store-apps, background-image

I am trying to make a Windows Store application and I would like to put the current start menu background image as my background image for the app but I don't know how to get the start menu background image. Anyone with some experience in this field? It doesn't matter if the solution is JS or C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't have access to that. That's considered user information and most user information is given on a strictly need-to-know basis. They could easily have that be a picture of their family, and that would be dangerous to give to random apps.

Comment: And another security reason: being able to grab the background image could help convince the user he is at his start menu when he isn't. This could be used to compromise the machine.

Comment: Well too bad, it would have been a great app :) Guess I will have to find other cool backgrounds :) Thanks for the reply!

Comment: One thing you *can* do is prompt them to select a background, including adding in all of the default ones (which you should be able to get off of your own system).

Comment: @NateDiamond Now that's a great suggestion